# Problemas con merge de sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

expertos tengo problemas con el siguiente codigo de sql en el cual hago uso de merge para actualizar 2 tablas.

```
USE [WebDBT]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MtoContratos-Obtener-Contratos-SAIB]
  @tblContrato ContratoSai READONLY,
  @tblDetalle DetalleContratoSai READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;


BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    BEGIN TRY

    /*================================================================================================================
    MERGE DE LA BASE DE DATOS PARA CONTRATOS
    ================================================================================================================*/
    MERGE MtoContrato with (holdlock) AS Target
    USING (Select NO_CONTRATO,RFC_PROVEEDOR,MONTO_ORIGINAL,MONTO_CONTRATO,MONTO_MINIMO,
        NO_LICITACION,EVENTO_COMPRANET,ESTADO_CONTRATO,NUM_PROVEEDOR,FECHA_EMISION,
        FECHA_INICIO,FECHA_TERMINACION,FECHA_FIRMA from @tblContrato) as Source
     ON (ltrim(rtrim(Source.NO_CONTRATO))=ltrim(rtrim(Target.NoContrato)))

    /*CUANDO EXISTE COINCIDENCIA*/
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    
        update set

        Target.NoContrato=  Source.NO_CONTRATO,
        Target.MontoOriginal=Source.MONTO_ORIGINAL,
        Target.MontoContrato=Source.MONTO_CONTRATO,
        Target.MontoMinimo=Source.MONTO_MINIMO,
        Target.NoLicitacion=Source.NO_LICITACION,
        Target.EstadoContrato=Source.ESTADO_CONTRATO,
        Target.NumeroProveedor=Source.NUM_PROVEEDOR,
        Target.FechaEmision=Source.FECHA_EMISION,
        Target.FechaFirma=Source.FECHA_FIRMA,
        Target.FechaInicio=Source.FECHA_INICIO,
        Target.FechaTerminacion=Source.FECHA_TERMINACION,
        Target.RfcProveedor=Source.RFC_PROVEEDOR,       
        Target.EventoCompranet=Source.EVENTO_COMPRANET                                  

    /*CUANDO NO EXISTE COINCIDENCIA*/       
    when not matched by Target then

     INSERT 
       (NoContrato,MontoOriginal,MontoContrato,MontoMinimo,NoLicitacion,
        EstadoContrato,NumeroProveedor,FechaEmision,FechaFirma,FechaInicio,
        FechaTerminacion,RfcProveedor,EventoCompranet)
    VALUES
       (NO_CONTRATO,MONTO_ORIGINAL,MONTO_CONTRATO,MONTO_MINIMO,NO_LICITACION,
        ESTADO_CONTRATO,NUM_PROVEEDOR,FECHA_EMISION,FECHA_FIRMA,FECHA_INICIO,
        FECHA_TERMINACION,RFC_PROVEEDOR,EVENTO_COMPRANET)

    --Cuando el registro existe en TARGET y no existe en SOURCE
    --se borra el registro en TARGET

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source AND YEAR(Target.FechaTerminacion) = 2020  THEN 
    DELETE;

    /*================================================================================================================
    MERGE DE LA BASE DE DATOS PARA DETALLE DE LOS CONTRATOS
    ================================================================================================================*/
    MERGE DetalleContrato With(holdlock) as Destinoo
    USING
    (Select NoContrato,Gpo,GEn,Esp,Dif,[Var],CantMax,CantMin,CantidadEjercida,PrecioClave,
        Descuento,PrecioNeto,Iva,PorcentajeAsignado from @tblDetalle) as Origenn
    ON  (ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.NoContrato))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.NoContrato)))
        and(ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.Gpo))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.Gpo))
        and ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.Gen))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.Gen))
        and ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.Esp))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.Esp))
        and ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.Dif))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.Dif))
        and ltrim(rtrim(Origenn.[Var]))=ltrim(rtrim(Destinoo.[Var]))
        )
    
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    
        update set
        Destinoo.NoContrato=Origenn.NoContrato,
        Destinoo.Gpo=Origenn.Gpo,
        Destinoo.Gen=Origenn.Gen,
        Destinoo.Esp=Origenn.Esp,
        Destinoo.Dif=Origenn.Dif,
        Destinoo.[Var]=Origenn.[Var],
        Destinoo.CantMax=Origenn.CantMax,
        Destinoo.CantMin=Origenn.CantMin,
        Destinoo.CantidadEjercida=Origenn.CantidadEjercida,
        Destinoo.PrecioClave=Origenn.PrecioClave,
        Destinoo.Descuento=Origenn.Descuento,
        Destinoo.PrecioNeto=Origenn.PrecioNeto,
        Destinoo.PorcentajeAsignado=Origenn.PorcentajeAsignado

    /*CUANDO NO EXISTE COINCIDENCIA*/       
    when NOT MATCHED by Target then

        insert (NoContrato,Gpo,gen,esp,dif,[Var],CantMax,CantMin,CantidadEjercida,
        CantMaxEnlace,CantMinEnlace,PrecioClave,Descuento,PrecioNeto,Iva,PorcentajeAsignado)
        values (NoContrato,Gpo,Gen,Esp,Dif,[Var],CantMax,CantMin,CantidadEjercida,
        0,0,PrecioClave,Descuento,PrecioNeto,Iva,PorcentajeAsignado)

    --Cuando el registro existe en TARGET y no existe en SOURCE
    --se borra el registro en TARGET
    
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;     


    

    /***************************************************************
     OBTENGO LOS NUEVOS REGISTRO Y LOS INSERTO EN LA TABLA DE EVENTOS SA
    ****************************************************************/
    INSERT INTO MtoEventosSai(NoLicitacion,EventoCompranet)
    select distinct NoLicitacion,EventoCompranet from MtoContrato A
    where not exists(select NoLicitacion,EventoCompranet from MtoEventosSai B
    where ltrim(rtrim(a.NoLicitacion))=ltrim(rtrim(b.NoLicitacion)) and ltrim(rtrim(a.EventoCompranet))=ltrim(rtrim(b.EventoCompranet)))
    and a.EventoCompranet is not null


    /*================================================================================================================
    IDENTIFICO A QUE EVENTO PERTECEN LOS EVENTOS DE COMPRANET
    ================================================================================================================*/
    UPDATE T1 SET T1.MtoProcedimientoId=T2.MtoProcedimientoId
    From MtoEventosSai T1, MtoProcedimiento T2
    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.EventoCompranet)))= UPPER(ltrim(rtrim(T2.NoLicitacion)))
    and t1.MtoprocedimientoId Is null
    

    /*================================================================================================================
    IDENTIFICO A QUE EVENTO PERTECEN LOS CONTRATOS
    ================================================================================================================*/
    Update t1 set t1.MtoProcedimientoId = t2.MtoProcedimientoId             
    from MtoContrato t1, MtoEventosSai t2
    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.NoLicitacion))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.NoLicitacion)))
    --and year(t1.FechaTerminacion)=2020
    and t1.MtoProcedimientoId is null


    /*================================================================================================================
    IDENTIFICO A QUE CONTRATO PERTENECE EL DETALLE
    ================================================================================================================*/
    Update DetalleContrato
                        set 
                        MtoContratoId = t2.MtoContratoId                
                    from DetalleContrato t1, MtoContrato t2
                    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.NoContrato))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.NoContrato)))
                    AND t1.MtoContratoId IS NULL;

    /*================================================================================================================
    IDENTIFICO A QUE PROVEEDOR PERTENECE EL CONTRATO EN MI CATALOGO
    ================================================================================================================*/
    Update t1
    set 
    t1.MtoproveedorId = t2.MtoProveedorId               
    from MtoContrato t1, MtoProveedor t2
    where UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.RfcProveedor))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.RfcProveedor)))
    AND T1.MtoProveedorId IS NULL



    /*================================================================================================================
    IDENTIFICO CLAVE DE DETALLE CONTRATO EN EL CATALOGO DE ARTICULOS
    ================================================================================================================*/

    Update DetalleContrato
            set 
                MtoCatArticuloId = t2.MtoCatArticuloId              
            from DetalleContrato t1, MtoCatArticulo t2
            where 
            UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Gpo))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.Gpo))) AND
            UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Gen))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.Gen))) AND
            UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Esp))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.Esp))) AND
            UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Dif))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.Dif))) AND
            UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t1.Var))) = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.Var))) AND
            T1.MtoCatArticuloId IS NULL


    COMMIT TRANSACTION 

    END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

 DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000),
      @ErrSeverity int 

SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
     @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY() 

RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1) 

END CATCH 
        
END
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente.

**The MERGE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.DetalleContrato_dbo.MtoContrato_MtoContratoId". The conflict occurred in database "WebDBT", table "dbo.DetalleContrato", column 'MtoContratoId'.**

ya busque porque podria ser el conflicto pero no lo identifico, ya ejecute las consultas indiviaules y las ejecuta sin ningun problema, sera posible que me puedan echar una mano.

muchas gracias

Comment: Para ir descartando errores te propongo que pruebes tu merge quitando algunas cláusulas ejemplo podrías quitar el when match probar ver si da error, luego quitar otra clausula probar y así hasta que encuentres en que clausula esta el error, así será más fácil hallar la solución a tu problema

Comment: gracias por el comentario, sabes que es lo raro que estaba funcionando a la perfeccion

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes una llave foránea que hace referencia a MtoContrato desde DetalleContrato. Al momento de eliminar una fila de MtoContrato que está siendo referenciada por DetalleContrato, se genera ese error.

Para solucionar esto, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Cambiar el código para realizar las operaciones por separado y que siempre elimine primero de la tabla de detalle y luego de la tabla maestra, pero que inserte primero en la tabla maestra y luego en la tabla detalle.
2. Modificar la llave foránea para agregar `ON CASCADE DELETE` para que al borrar las filas de la tabla maestra, se borren también las de la tabla detalle. Tienes que ser muy cuidadoso con esta opción porque facilita la opción de borrar información y puede generar accidentes más fácilmente.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tus comentarios los voy a tomar en cuenta.